# Learning GoLang

Tags: self-learning, programming

I want to learn Go Language as it is popular these days. I tried some demo programs on https://play.golang.org/.

Do we have some good resources to learn Golang? It looks pretty similar to C, C++ in some ways.

Comment: What is your goal?  What is your rough level / background?

Comment: I am a new Ph.D. student. I need to master Golang before I graduate so I can apply in 'FAANG' companies

Comment: [This](https://golang.org/doc) is the official documentation.

Comment: Thanks @J.G. ..

Comment: PHD in what?, what is your programming experience?

Comment: Ph.D. in Information Quality. I have worked as a programmer analyst for almost 4 years in a Multi-National Company. I have some knowledge about C, C++, Cobol, Python. Among the databases; I prefer SQL Server to other databases...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to mention some sites, books, and YouTube which I found for Golang:

**Static Sites**

Effective Go is an official resource which is available for free from the official Go website https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html

Go by Example is a website with the most common examples https://gobyexample.com

the Golang FAQ section https://golang.org/doc/faq

**YouTubes and Video sites**

https://www.youtube.com/c/toddmcleod-learn-to-code/playlists

https://gameswithgo.org/

**Books**

Head First Go by Jay McGavren

[https://www.amazon.com/Head-First-Go-Jay-McGavren/dp/1491969555](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491969555)

An Introduction To Programming in Go by Caleb Doxsey

http://www.golang-book.com/books/intro

Go in Action by Brian Ketelsen, Erik Saint Martin, and William Kennedy

[https://www.amazon.com/Go-Action-William-Kennedy/dp/1617291781](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1617291781)

a free online book on how to get started on Go http://www.golangbootcamp.com/book/

there are many more resources which we can search online...